# Number of Inputs selected in selectInput() function in R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, selectinput

This might be a very basic question but I have been banging my head for this for the past 2 days.

Is there any way to get the number of options that are chosen in the dropdown box which is created by using SelectInput() (Multiple options are acceptable) function.

Depending upon the Number of Inputs, I need to change the size (width, height) of the ggplot in the dashboard.

Thanks in Advance

David.